# In Xamarin.Android, are constant strings allocated in Java?

Tags: xamarin.android, mono

In Xamarin.Android, if I set the text on a `android.widget.TextView` to a **constant** string like this:

```
var label = new TextView(context);
label.Text = "Hello";  // Does a Java string get allocated here?
```

does a Java string get **allocated** at runtime and `"Hello"` gets stored in it?

The 2nd question: If a Java string gets allocated, is there a way to **avoid** the **extra** allocation?

Here's what I mean by "extra": If you compare it to C#, in C# a constant (literal) string interned, it becomes a part of the intern pool, it only gets allocated **once** when app is started. Is there a similar mechanism in Xamarin.Android ?

Comment: Anything that passes from Mono to Java in runtime code is using a managed callable wrapper (MCW) and thus yes, there is a "double" allocation, one within Mono and one within the JVM, same if you are going the other way via Android callable wrappers (ACW). You "could" avoid it by using JNI and calling the Java-based SetText directly, but if the string is not already allocated within an Android-based resource (string.xml, etc..) you will end up with a double allocation if it passes through the Mono VM.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! But please help me to make sure I understand correctly. You say I could avoid the double string allocation, if I would use JNI instead. But isn't what Mono is doing already? Per my little understanding, the MCW is actually a JNI bridge, it uses JNI to call Java.

Comment: I mean, using JNI already involves allocating the string on the heap. So even if I'd call setting the text on the `TextView` myself using JNI, wouldn't I be doing the same thing which Mono is doing?

Comment: For the android application, every app will have a jvm when the app start. If you set the textview's text by `label.Text = "Hello";`, the jvm will put the string `Hello` into the constant pool.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Correct both .NET and Java work in a similar way, they have a string pool for literal strings you put in the code. But my question was different. My question is about Xamarin/.NET Mobile. What happens in order for the string to get to the Java world?

Comment: All the app on the android just have a jvm, even though we use the xamarin.android, the code running is still java when it is packed to a apk file. If all the objects will be allocated twice, the storage and the performance will be wasted.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I'm surprised you say "all the app on the android just hava a jvm". It's not what the official Xamarin documentation say. There's two garbage collectors, two virtual machines, .NET and JVM. .NET calls Java through JNI.

Comment: All right, sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @SushiHangover Would you please help me understand how it works? Please see my last question. Doesn't MCW already uses JNI?